# How to Get Full Resolution & Uncompressed Image Data with Android Camera？

Tags: android, bitmap, camera

I want to get a full resolution（and not compressed）image data, then i can do some image processing.

As far as i know, the android api takePicture (shutter, raw, jpg) can do something.But what i need is not a compressed JPEG data, a uncompressed image data instead.Also I knew the raw callback doesn't work according to some posts i have read.

I also found the api onPreviewFrame, and the larggest picture size i got from this is 1280*720(use setPreviewSize) while the original image i caputure from the camera is a resolution of 1952*3264.

Also, Intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, uri) may be help, but it likely that the file of the uri should be a jpeg file which is a compressed format.

But is there anyway to get a full size(the same as captured) and uncompressed(not a JPEG) image data?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The documentation for takePicture() clearly says that raw data can be requested, but the callback is optional. Today,  most of devices do not support raw callback. This should not be a surprise: modern cameras perform Jpeg compression in hardware, and the memory bus between the camera and the application processor cannot handle 24 Megabyte of raw data fast enough (for a modest 8 megapixel camera).

Avoid temptation to use preview callback instead of takePicture(): even at same resolution,  image qualiity of a still picture will be better. Preview image may have imprecise autofocus, stabilization, exposure and even white balance.

Comment: Thank you very much. Do you mean that we can't get uncompressed image data with android camera api on most devices?

Comment: *Do you mean that we can't get uncompressed image data with android camera api on most devices?* Exactly.

Comment: Is this true now in 2016?

Comment: @Mr.Newman, thanks for asking: the times change, and the API too. The camera API v.1 that almost 3 years ago felt outdated and ridiculously limited has been officially deprecated by Google, and the new shiny camera2 API has been introduced. Still, the market share of devices compatible with this new API is less than 50%, with KitKat being the single most popular platform today (at 32%). Furthermore, most of Android 5 devices support of camera2 is crippled (a.k.a. [limited](https://spectrastudy.com/camera2-api-on-mwc-2015-devices/#LIMITED_partial_support_your_mileage_may_vary)).

Comment: Thank you very much for  your answer! Can you provide some links or another info about this ? How to write picture (high resolution)  to the RAM without writing to flash (SD card)?

Comment: @Mr.Newman try [GitHub](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-Camera2Raw) or [YouTube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UgEQwBqHkSQ)

Comment: I tried( About 10 hours. The best info about it is your answer )) great thank you)