# Can I save the photo to RAM in Android without sd card

Tags: android, android-camera

HelloEveryone! I want to know some principal thing. Is there exists a method to take a picture (with good resolution) from android device without saving it in hard memory (only in RAM). I tried to:

1. use `TakePicture(shutter, raw, jpg)`, but resolution of the resulting JPG is very low and RAW working with very few number of devices. [Was asked here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19478101/how-to-get-full-resolution-uncompressed-image-data-with-android-camera)
2. give the control to Google Camera, but this way required some temporary file in the hard memory (to write picture)

How can I do this. Or is it impossible? Any help! Thank you!

Comment: Storing uncompressed images in memory using a bitmap is asking for an OutOfMemoryException. These files can end up very large and could easily crash your app. Is there any reason you don't want these written to temporary files

Comment: Let it be compressed. Usual JPG (from custom camera) is not very big and have good resolution. But the function TakePicture returns very very very bad resolution. But without temporary files. It is principal requirement. Is it possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It depends on your phone. Many phones do not need external sd card because they already have a internal one. So I suggest you check the hardware information of your phone first. If it do not have a external sd card, you can try to use [camera2](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/camera2/package-summary.html)

to take videos and pictures. Pictures and videos can be stored in RAM. But if you want to access the pictures stored in RAM, you need to root your phone first.

Comment: Internal storage also inacceptible. Does camera2 use storage? Or RAM only? Does camera2 work on most devices or only on new and expensive?

Comment: camera2 is the newest api for camera usage. It requires Android version higher than 5.0 (most phones fit in the requirement )

Comment: It can use both of them.

Comment: Thank you, for your answer! Is there exists another way for android < 5.0 and without using storages (only RAM)?

Comment: The depreciated API Camera. I am not sure about it because I have not used it before. You can also check the demo of camera2 in android developer website.